# Areal Interpolation polygon to polygon using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, interpolation, multi-polygon

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.0.

I have two `multipolygons` and I would like to interpolate the values of one polygon to the other. I found the `Areal Interpolation tool` which does exactly that. One of required option/argument is that the tool asks the user to choose the dataset type `average`, `rate` or `event`.

And, that's where I am stuck because the values are categorical ranging from `0-10`.

What datatype should be selected for such an interpolation?

Comment: Can you please reflect a bit more on your categories, what 0 or 10 mean?

Comment: @fatih_dur means `0 = Flood Factor (FF) is 0` and vice versa is true for `10`.

Comment: I'd use average and just convert/round the results to the nearest integer category

Comment: @Brennan, average won't work since the values are categorical.

Comment: If the categories map linearly to whatever is it they measure, why not just treat them as integers, average them, then round the result to the nearest integer? If the categories are not along a linear spectrum, like land use classes, I'm not sure how you'd do any sort of interpolation, as opposed to just taking the dominant class in a given polygon.

Comment: Your data categorical but it is nominal at the same time (FF 1 is smaller than FF 2) however it may not be numerical (FF2 is **two** times of FF1). Still, I think you should select "Average" option since you would like to interpolate those values into the smaller polygons and the size of the polygons on the receiving end do not matter. If we were talking about some kind of density, then rate would be logical.

Comment: I suggest adding an integer column first, then using whatever SME knowledge proportionally translates the categories to integers calculate the new field, then use average to interpolate, then finally recategorize afterwards.

Comment: This discussion on the Areal Interpolation process helps explain the statistics involved and IMO supports the use of Average unless you're data are derivative based like flow rates or slopes. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/using-areal-interpolation-to-predict-to-new-polygons.htm